# C++ string pointer doesn't have the same memory address as the string it points to

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I wrote a simple program to see how C++ handles pointers to string objects (new to OOP), and I was suprised to see that `string* as` which was assigned the memory address of `string a`, didn't store a value equivalent to `&a`. Also, the console didn't print the value to `*as`. Could this be an error on my end or the system, or am missing something fundamental here?

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

string a = "asdf";
string* as = &a;
string* as_holder = &a;

int main()
{
    cout << "a = " << a <<  "\t" << "&a = " << &a << " *as = " << *as << endl
        << "as = " << as << endl
        << "++as = " << ++as << endl
        << "*as = " << *as << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
a = asdf     &a = 011ff68C *as = 
as = 011FF6A8
++as = 011FF6A8
*as =
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the actual output.

Comment: Also note that `++as` and the following `*as` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Your question does not have relation to your code because you have not shown the area of the code that is not giving correct output

Comment: I get a warning http://codepad.org/HCtDIYHQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my test of the valid portion of your program (the first two lines of `cout`), the printout showed the same address:

```
a = asdf    &a = 0x8049c90 *as = asdf
as = 0x8049c90
```

([link to a demo](http://ideone.com/I81VBF))

Lines three and four, however, amount to undefined behavior: once you do `++as`, you are moving the pointer to the next `std::string` in an "array of strings" (which does not exist). Therefore, the subsequent attempt at dereferencing `as` is *undefined behavior*.

If you would like to obtain a pointer to the data of your string, such that you could move to the next character by incrementing the pointer, you could use `c_str()` member function, like this:

```
const char *as = a.c_str();
as++;
cout << as << endl; // This would print "sdf"
```

Comment: what exactly does c_str() do?

Comment: @Bbvarghe `c_str()` ([link to documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)) returns a null-terminated pointer to the character representation of the string.

Comment: also, does making *as a `const` still mean the value of `as` can still be modified?

Comment: @Bbvarghe Writing to pointer obtained through `c_str()` is undefined behavior.